# python how to calculate age and name in one function

Tags: python

```py
from datetime import date

def date_person():

    name = input('Enter your name and press ENTER')
    surname =input ('Enter your surname and press ENTER')
    birth_year= input('Enter your birth_year and press ENTER')
    
    name_list=name.split()
    surname_list=surname.split()
    
    print(name_list, surname_list, birth_year)
    first = name[1][0]
    second = surname[1][0]
    days_in_year = 365.2425 
    age= int((date.today())- birth_year).days/days_in_year

    print(name)
    print(surname)
    print(birth_year)
    print("your initial:", first.upper(),'.',second.upper(),'.', "and your age:",  age )
  
date_person()
```

I have a mistake with DateTime. What is wrong?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your birth_year into date object:

```
birth_year= int(input('Enter your birth_year and press ENTER'))
birth_year_date = date(birth_year, 1, 1)
```

then calc diff between dates will return a datetime.timeDelta object, now you can get days attribute:

```
age= int((date.today() - birth_year_date).days/days_in_year)
```

Comment: thank you very much!! now it is working !! :)

Answer (score -2):

you should be sure birth_year type is int , for solve this problem use

correct_birth_year = int(birth_year)